# Help displaying related categories

Tags: wp-query, categories

How would I go about displaying related categories instead of the follow which displays related tags. Please any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance

```
if(!function_exists('solstice_related_post')) {
    function solstice_related_post() {
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

        if(!empty($tags) && is_array($tags)):
            $simlar_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;

            ?>

            <div class="related-posts">
                <h6><?php esc_html_e('YOU MIGHT ALSO LIKE', 'solstice-theme'); ?></h6>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'tag__in'             => array($simlar_tag),
                        'post__not_in'        => array($post->ID),
                        'posts_per_page'      => 3,
                        'meta_query'          => array(array('key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'compare' => 'EXISTS')),
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                    );
                    $re_query = new WP_Query($args);
                    while ($re_query->have_posts()) : $re_query->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <article <?php post_class('blog-post col-md-4'); ?>>
                            <header>
                                <figure>
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('solstice-small'); ?>
                                </figure>
                                <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_the_permalink()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <div class="meta">
                                    <span><?php echo get_the_category_list( ' , ', 'solstice-theme' );?></span>
                                    <span><time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?>"><?php the_time('F d, Y'); ?></time></span>
                                </div><!-- /meta -->
                            </header>
                        </article>
                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </div><!-- /row -->
            </div><!-- /related-posts -->
            <?php
        endif;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);`
with

```
wp_get_post_terms($post->ID);
```

All parameter and details can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

and change the $args parameter

```
$args = array(
    'category__in'        => array($simlar_tag),
    'post__not_in'        => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'meta_query'          => array(array('key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'compare' => 'EXISTS')),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
  );
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response! However, no related post show after the change.  Any ideas?

Here' what I changed the code to:

```
if(!function_exists('solstice_related_post')) {
```

function solstice_related_post() {
    global $post;
    $tags = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID);

```
if(!empty($tags) && is_array($tags)):
  $simlar_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;

?>

<div class="related-posts">
  <h6><?php esc_html_e('YOU MIGHT ALSO LIKE', 'solstice-theme'); ?></h6>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    $args = array(
'category__in'        => array($simlar_tag),
'post__not_in'        => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'      => 3,
'meta_query'          => array(array('key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'compare' => 'EXISTS')),
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
```

);
          $re_query = new WP_Query($args);
          while ($re_query->have_posts()) : $re_query->the_post();
        ?>
        >

#### ">

">